# How to use hotjar with ember ?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, statistics, hotjar

I need to use hotjar for work, but i have some difficulties to set it up. The project is an ember project, and i have found this project to integrate hotjar : https://github.com/byrnedo/ember-hotjar

In this github page, it says : "in routes and controller you will have _hj.push available", but i can't manage to make it work and i can't find any information about how to set it up.

I added this in config/environment.js :

```
hotjar: {
  id: my-id
},
```

And in a route, if i do this :

```
console.log(this.get('_hj'))
```

I get this result in the console :

```
ƒ () {
    (window.hj.q = window.hj.q || []).push(arguments);
  }
```

Meaning that hotjar is successfully installed, but when i'm trying to something like :

```
this.get('_hj').push('trigger', 'hello_world');
```

An error appears saying :

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.get(...).push is not a function
```

Does anyone know how to make it work or if i'm making something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Uncaught TypeError: this.get(...).push is not a function

Is a result of you attempting to call `.push` on a function. As in, from your `console.log`, we can see that `this.get('_hj')` is a function, and you attempted to call `.push` on it. You'd get the same error if you tried:

```
let x = function(){ }
x.push()
```

Anyway, let's get to the bottom of it. The addon has provided an initializer [ember-hotjar](https://github.com/byrnedo/ember-hotjar/blob/master/app/initializers/ember-hotjar.js) that invokes:

```
import hj  from '../hotjar/main';
...
let h =  hj.create();
application.register('hotjar:main', h, {instantiate: false});
application.inject('controller', '_hj', 'hotjar:main');
application.inject('route',      '_hj', 'hotjar:main');
```

Whatever `hotjar/main` exports is used to create `h`. This is registered in the dependency injection container for ember with the key `hotjar:main` as a shared object (ie `hotjar:main` holds a reference to an already instantiated object and not a factory). Then, because of the `inject`, all routes and all controllers are getting access to said object via `this._hj`. Please see [registration](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/applications/dependency-injection/#toc_factory-registrations) or [the injections](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/applications/dependency-injection/#toc_factory-injections) section of the guides for more information.

So now, we need to investigate the [main.js](https://github.com/byrnedo/ember-hotjar/blob/master/app/hotjar/main.js) function that is exporting `hj`

```
var  hj = window.hj = window.hj || function(){(window.hj.q=window.hj.q||[]).push(arguments)};

...

export default {
  create:  function () {
    return hj;
  }
};
```

this is assigning `window.hj || function(){(window.hj.q=window.hj.q||[]).push(arguments)};` to both `hj` and `window.hj`, which ultimately means that in your controller, `this._hj` === `function(){(window.hj.q=window.hj.q||[]).push(arguments)};`

So having seen all of that, I'm not really sure what you're expecting `push` to do. I think you may just want `this._hj('trigger', 'hello_world')`? Best of luck

Comment: Thanks ! Indeed i only had to do this._hj('trigger', 'hello_world'), that was so simple.. I should have think more, it seems obvious to me now !